# Automatically create folder of same name on file creation

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there any way for me to set up sublime to automatically create a folder of the same name when I create certain files.

I create landing pages that all have a `lp_` prefix to the filename, I would like to watch for when a file with this name is created and then automatically create a folder of the same name in another directory (for css and images).

Would this be possible with a plugin or something like Grunt?

Example:

Create file: `lp_test.php`

Automate Folder Creation: `/lp/lp_test/`

Comment: Very helpful thanks for that

Comment: No problem.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Ha, would you be able to divulge any more information?

Comment: I could. Your question was simply "*Would this be possible?*", the answer to which is yes. If you are wondering **how** to do it, you need to say so. I'm not trying to be snarky, just making a point about being precise when asking questions. I can't begin to tell you how many questions I've seen where the only sentence with a question mark in it is some variation of "*Is this even possible?*" Just trying to improve SO one post at a time :)

Comment: At any rate, do you know Python? That's the language plugins are written in.

Comment: @James Did my answer helped you solving your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a plugin that extends [`EventListener`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener) and overrides (for example) `on_post_save_async`. You can use this simple example as base:

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin, os

# We extend event listener
class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    # This method is called every time a file is saved (not only the first time is saved)
    def on_post_save_async(self, view):
        variables = view.window().extract_variables()
        fileBaseName = variables['file_base_name'] # File name without extension
        path = 'C:/desiredPath/css/' + fileBaseName

        if fileBaseName.startswith('lp_') and not os.path.exists(path):
            os.mkdir(path)
```

**EDIT:** changed `on_post_save` to `on_post_save_async` as it runs in a different thread and does not block the application. Thanks [MattDMo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628037/automatically-create-folder-of-same-name-on-file-creation/31629300?noredirect=1#comment51205975_31629300) for commenting it and for adding python highlighting.

Comment: Since OP is using ST3, `on_post_save_async()` would probably be a better choice.

Comment: Sorry for late response i have been busy with other projects... This is unfortunately a little too advanced for me as I do not know any Python. I thank you for your help though and hopefully it can help others!

Comment: @James You should not need to add new python code (other than change the path), my example should be enough. Step 1: use _Tools>New Plugin_ and set the given code as content. Step 2: save it as _example.py_ inside _Pacjkages/User_ folder. Step 3: create the destination folder (_C:/desiredPath/css/_). Step 4: create a file and save it as _lp_test.php_ and the plugin should create the desired file inside _css_ folder.

Comment: Having some trouble, I have followed the steps you gave but plugin does not seem to be working. I think I may have the path declared wrong (I am on Mac). 

Path I gave is:

path = '/Users/jameshusband/Dropbox/css/' + fileBaseName

Comment: You can open console to see if plugin is loaded and to see if some error appears.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: After saving the plugin do I need to enable it at all? Im just trying to find out if it is actually running in the background

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84994/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-31628037-sublime-text-automatic-folder-crea).